# How do I control 2 PR2 robots in gazebo at the same time?

Tags: ros, namespace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can teleoperate on pr2 robot through roslaunch pr2_teleop_general pr2_teleop_general_keyboard.launch.
I am also able to move pr2 robot by writing a C++ script. But I want to have 2 pr2 robots in my customised world and control move both of them. I am using ROS-Indigo with gazebo version 2.2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236625/how-do-i-control-2-pr2-robots-in-gazebo-at-the-same-time-?/) by [Pikachu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22900/pikachu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2016-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need namespaces for launching multiple robots. And namespacing packages, frames, topics... are a really big work. Also namespacing PR2 is the biggest version of this problem because it has many many packages for namespacing. I'll write small tutorial for how to namespace robots and doing navigation with them later. But You can follow this sequence;

First look at urdf for tf. Joints, frames must be unic, secondly [group](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/group) your `.launch` files with `<group ns="robot_name"></group>` tag. Then look at the topics, which one is not connected? Which one is not published? `rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph` is really helpful for this job. Look at rqt_graph for understanding it. Then Try to [remap](http://answers.ros.org/question/198873/how-to-changeremap-ros-node-name-in-launch-file/) them.

I'm currently running navigation stack with multiple robots in gazebo wtihout editing sources. Also if you have custom packages, You may need to rename some frames etc.

And I suggest, please don't do this with PR2 :)

---

Originally posted by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) with karma: 856 on 2016-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pikachu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22900/pikachu/) on 2016-06-10**:
Hi, Thanks for answering. i will try with what you mentioned.
Can I know how are you using navigation stack with multiple robots and what robots are you using? I also need to do something similar.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-06-10**:
I'm running one common `map_server` and common `/map` topic. But `amcl`, `move_base`... nodes are in their robot's namespace: for ex: `/robot1/amcl` , `/robot2/amcl`. For doing this, You must enter robot special parameters in your launch file. For example; There is a parameter in `global_costmap`;

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-06-10**:
in move_base launch file, firstly I'm getting other parameters from yaml, but this one is robot specific:

```
<param name="global_costmap/obstacles_layer/scan/sensor_frame" value="$(arg robot_name)/base_laser_link" />
```

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-06-10**:
That `robot_name` is the namespace of robot and I'm passing this parameter in every recursive launch.